# How to get name in json coinmarketcap? PHP

Tags: php, json

How to get name if I put BTC ?

```
$url = file_get_contents(https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/);
$json = json_decode($url,true);
```

and result

```
            [
            {
                "id": "bitcoin", 
                "name": "Bitcoin", 
                "symbol": "BTC", 
            }, 
            {
      }, 
        {
            "id": "ethereum", 
            "name": "Ethereum", 
            "symbol": "ETH", 

        }, 
        {
            "id": "bitcoin-cash", 
            "name": "Bitcoin Cash", 
            "symbol": "BCH", 
        }, 
]
```

eg.
when I put   "BTC"
and need output = "Bitcoin"

or put "ETH"
output = "Ethereum"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find proper record using:

```
$key = array_search('BTC', array_column($json, 'symbol'));
```

And then (if `$key` found) get the record like this:

```
$record = $json[$key];
var_dump($record);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probalby u need to use full coins name (lowercase) as described in official docs https://coinmarketcap.com/api/ look into paragraph *Ticker (Specific Currency)*